# Returning a pointer from a member function in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

Hello I have a class with a function that returns a pointer:

```
int* Maze::GetStart()
{
    int startNode = 1;

    return &startNode;
}
```

Will the value of startNode be erased after the function returns the pointer?

If I did this instead would the value be saved?

```
int Maze::GetStart()
{
    int startNode = 1;

    return startNode ;
}

main
{
    int* pStart = maze.GetStart();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will the value of startNode be erased
>   after the function returns the
>   pointer?

The variable `startNode` will cease to exist once the function `GetStart()` returns, so in that sense, yes.

**But**, your code opens up a huge opportunity for undefined behavior by returning addresses to things that will disappear once `GetStart()` returns. If the caller attempts to dereference the returned `node*`, anything can happen. Also, the code can't possibly compile as-is since you can't implicitly cast an `int*` to a `node*`.

However, if you're returning by value, then you should be fine:

```
int Maze::GetStart() 
{ 
    int startNode = 1; 
    return startNode; 
    // return 1; // Why not do this?
} 

int pStart = maze.GetStart(); // Get returned value as int, not pointer to int.
```

Comment: Okay but I want the pointer to the returned value. Will my updated code point to the value 1?

Comment: @Arizona1911: What do you mean by "a pointer to the returned value"? Why do you need to do that?

Comment: I would like to do this but in one line int start = maze.GetStart(); int* pStart = &start;

Comment: @Arizona1911: I have a feeling that a better solution exists for what you want to do. What are you really trying to do? Why are pointers so necessary?

Comment: I don't have a good reason to use pointers. I will rethink my approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Returning address of a variable allocated on stack does not make sense at all. The life time of the variable `startNode` gets over as soon as the function `GetStart()` returns. It does not matter if it is a free function or member function.

I think, in gcc/g++ there is a warning for this.

Based on the question edit:

If you want to modify the variable and save the **modified** state then it must be declared `static`. See [static local variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_variable#Static_local_variables).